# shell parsing a line to look for a certain tag

Tags: bash, shell

I am planning to create a simple script to edit a file based on values stored within a properties file.
So essentially I am planning to loop through each line in the original file, when it comes across a certain tag within a line say "/#" it will get the text following the tag i.e. certs and then implement a function to parse through the properties file to get certain values and add them to the original file. 
So for example the file would have the following line:

"/#certs"

I am not sure how best to search for the tag, I was planning to have an if to find the /# and then split the remaining text to get the string.

```
while read line
    do

    #need to parse line to look for tag


    echo line >> ${NEW_FILE}
    done < ${OLD_FILE}
```

Any help would e greatly appreciated

=====================================

EDIT:

My explanation was a bit poor; apologies. I am merely trying to get the text following the /# - i.e. I just want to get the string value that precedes it. I can then call a function based on what the text is.

Comment: Your question is tagged sh bash ksh -- does that mean "any" or "all" of these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BASH regex capabilities:

```
while read line
do
if [[ "$line" =~ ^.*/#certs(.*)$ ]]; then
    # do your processing here 
    # echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} is the part after /#certs
    echo echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} >> ${NEW_FILE}
fi
done < ${OLD_FILE}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is portable to Bourne shell and thus, of course, ksh and Bash.

```
case $line in
    '/#'* ) tag="${line#/\#}" ;;
esac
```

To put it into some sort of context, here is a more realistic example of how you might use it:

```
while read line; do
    case $line in
        '/#'* ) tag="${line#/\#}" ;;
        *) continue ;; # skip remainder of loop for lines without a tag
    esac
    echo "$tag"
    # Or maybe do something more complex, such as
    case $tag in
        cert)
           echo 'We have a cert!' >&2 ;;
        bingo)
           echo 'You are the winner.' >&2
           break # terminate loop
           ;;
        esac
done <$OLD_FILE >$NEW_FILE
```

Comment: Not sure if the backslash is required / useful.  Bash works with or without it, but I suspect other shells might need it.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you can search for strings and manipulate them in one step using `sed` the stream editor.

```
echo $line | sed -rn 's:^.*/#(certs.+):\1:p'
```

This will print only the relevant parts after the `/#` of the relevant lines.

Comment: I am trying to get the text part after the /# ie, I want to get the "certs" bit - I will then execute a function to do stuff based on what that text is. Is this still possible with sed?

Comment: I've modified the answer so that sed prints only the part after `/#`.

Comment: But it's still looking for `certs` rather than any tag.