# shell bash, how to split a string to get the text after a tag

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to split a string to get the text after a string tag. I have been told using sed might be wise, but am unsure how to implement it.

I have the following text in a file:

```
/#text
/#difftext
....
```

I basically want to loop through to and get the text after the /#

Here is what I have so far:

```
while read line
    do
    if [[ ${line} == */#" ]]
    #split line to get text

done < ${FILE}
```

Comment: Then what is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089322/shell-parsing-a-line-to-look-for-a-certain-tag

Comment: oh, didn't notice it is a duplicated question....

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po '/#\K.*'
```

or

```
sed 's@/#@@'
```

Comment: +1, but if just the tag name is wanted: `/#\K\S+`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the line in a variable you can use string substitution:

```
$ line='/#text /#difftext ....'
$ echo ${line##*/#}
difftext ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
  if [[ ${line} =~ ^.*/# ]]; then
    echo ${line##*#}
  fi
done <file
```